# vb.net: Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference occurs with random.next

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, random

I am attempting to randomly generate a number between (and including) 1 and 4 to randomly select an object (in this case an asteroid) and tells it to move to a location and unhide (spawn).

```
If Globals.pathA = True Then
        Globals.astroidspawn_a1 = Random.Next(1, 4)
```

And then

```
If Globals.astroidspawn_a1 = 1 Then
            astroid1.Location = New Point(800, 55)
            astroid1.Visible = True
        End If
```

This second section repeats multiple times resulting in the spawning asteroids.

The code "Random.Next" is seen as a code error, stating "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an ***instance*** of the Random class. The preferred method is to use a `Shared` variable as this improves the randomness.

Place the following in your Form/Class:

```
Private Shared _rnd As New Random
```

The when you want a value:

```
Globals.astroidspawn_a1 = _rnd.Next(1, 4)
```

Answer (score -1):

`Next()` is a function that is designed to be called from an instance of the `Random` class. First you need to declare an object variable and initialize it, then call `Next()` on the object variable.

One quick way to fix the code is to instantiate a new `Random` class as needed before calling `Next()`:

```
If Globals.pathA = True Then
    Dim randomizer = New Random()
    Globals.astroidspawn_a1 = randomizer.Next(1, 4)
```

One drawback to this approach is that random numbers aren't truly random - they are known as pseudo-random, taking a seed value and generating new numbers based on the seed. A sequence of numbers based on the same seed will be identical every time. In the example above the default seed value is based on the clock time, which means if it is called inside of a loop it has the potential to generate the same value many times in a row.

A way to fix that is to explicitly pass in a new seed to the `Random` object constructor that is not based on the clock time. Here's one approach:

```
If Globals.pathA = True Then
    Dim randomizer = New Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())
    Globals.astroidspawn_a1 = randomizer.Next(1, 4)
```

This should create truly random values as the seed is then randomized as well.

Comment: Not a good solution IMO as It's much more efficient to create *one* `Shared` Random class *once* than to keep creating instances and guids